# ymajorgrids is printed over area style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    area style,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    bar width=0.6cm
    ]

\addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!20, draw=black!40] coordinates{(0.0,1) (0.75,1) 
(0.75,1) (1.5,1) 
(1.5,1) (2.25,1) 
(2.25,0) (3.0,0) 
(3.0,0) (3.75,0) 
(3.75,2) (4.5,2) 
(4.5,1) (5.25,1) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see below, the lines of `ymajorgrids` are over the "bars" of my drawing.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `area legend` style sets `axis on top`. To get the desired result you just delete it and rename `mark=no` to `mark=none`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymajorgrids=true,
        bar width=0.6cm,
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            mark=none,
            ybar interval,
            fill=black!20,
            draw=black!40,
        ] coordinates{
            (0.0,1) (0.75,1)
            (0.75,1) (1.5,1)
            (1.5,1) (2.25,1)
            (2.25,0) (3.0,0)
            (3.0,0) (3.75,0)
            (3.75,2) (4.5,2)
            (4.5,1) (5.25,1)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Running your MWE I get the desired result, but the picture shows the grid in foreground. So it seems to me that the picture (grid overlays the bars) is not the result of the code. `area style` followed by `axis on top=false` works too.

Comment: @esdd, thanks for the hint. Missed to TeX again after checking something and thus uploaded the wrong image ... This is corrected now.

Comment: @esdd, of course your solution also works, but I don't see where OP "uses" the area legend and thus I decided to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers, %<-added
    area style,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    bar width=0.6cm
    ]

\addplot+[ybar interval, mark=no, fill=black!20, draw=black!40,
on layer=axis foreground%<-added
] coordinates{(0.0,1) (0.75,1) 
(0.75,1) (1.5,1) 
(1.5,1) (2.25,1) 
(2.25,0) (3.0,0) 
(3.0,0) (3.75,0) 
(3.75,2) (4.5,2) 
(4.5,1) (5.25,1) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]